# dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs28_28.1~1.git5a223c7f2e-kk3+20.04_amd64.deb

Tags: install

Given:

Linux Mint 20.3

I try to install Emacs 28

like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install emacs28
```

But rise error:

```
electing previously unselected package libm17n-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libm17n-0_1.8.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libm17n-0:amd64 (1.8.0-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../emacs28_28.1~1.git5a223c7f2e-kk3+20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking emacs28 (28.1~1.git5a223c7f2e-kk3+20.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs28_28.1~1.git5a223c7f2e-kk3+20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/emacs-module.h', which is also in package emacs-common 1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs28_28.1~1.git5a223c7f2e-kk3+20.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```